# Batch: want to sort the web addresses by ping time and write it to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I want to sort a list of websites regarding their ping time.
I have written the following code to find the fastest ping time
but when I put my loop into another one for sorting the list I get ECHO is OFF in the output file.
Can anyone help me complete the code and help me with the ECHO output?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

echo #Autogenerated regarding ping time> sitePingList.txt

set serverList= "www.site1.com" "www.site2.com" "www.site3.com"

rem Initialize variables
set "selected="
set "min=99999999"

echo - Testing -----------------------------
rem Enumerate the hosts to check
for %%a in ( %serverList% ) do (

    rem Ping the host and retrieve the average roundtrip
    for /f "tokens=6 delims== " %%r in ('
    ping -n 1 "%%~a" ^| findstr /r /c:"^  .*ms$"
    ') do for /f "delims=ms" %%t in ("%%r") do (
        echo "%%~a" : %%t ms

        rem Determine if the current host has a lower rtt
        rem if %%t geq min or min is already 0, then we have
        rem a division by 0, else a lower rtt has been found
        set /a "1/(min/(%%t+1))" && (
        set "selected=%%~a"
        set "min=%%t"
        )
    )
) 2>nul 

echo - Selected ----------------------------
echo %selected% : %min%
set ping1="fastest1: %selected%, user:test, password:123456"
set ping1=%ping1:"=%
>>  sitePingList.txt echo %ping1%
```

I have checked what @lit says:
what is in the $result value is as bellow:

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    --------
NIMA-LAPTOP   www.ibm.com     148.251.160.242                                           32       100
NIMA-LAPTOP   www.hp.com      23.58.222.80                                              32       151
```

As you can see the output is two simple lines with only ms no other text.
Also note that you should change the syntax of the testConnection and change the targetName to computerName

```
PS C:\Users\Nima> $Targets = @('www.ibm.com', 'www.hp.com')
>> $Results = @()
>> foreach ($Target in $Targets) {
>>     $Results += Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName $Target
>> }
>> $Results |
>>     Sort-Object -Property Latency |
>>     ForEach-Object {
>>         "{0} {1}ms" -f @($_.Destination, $_.Latency)
>>     }
 ms
 ms
```

Comment: If that is your complete script, there is no way for `%ping1%` to be empty, which would be the only possible condition for `echo is OFF` to appear in `sitePingList.txt`. Are you sure the file you wrote to and the file you checked is the same? (Check the date/time stamp).

Answer (score 1):

This script pings a list of destinations and sorts the result by latency. It can be invoked using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Get-PingList.ps1"
```

=== Get-PingList.ps1

```
$Targets = @('www.ibm.com', 'www.hp.com')
$Results = @()
foreach ($Target in $Targets) {
    $Results += Test-Connection -Count 1 -TargetName $Target
}
$Results |
    Sort-Object -Property Latency |
    ForEach-Object {
        "{0} {1}ms" -f @($_.Destination, $_.Latency)
    }
```

=== Example output

```
PS C:\src\t> .\Get-FastestPing.ps1
www.hp.com 46ms
www.ibm.com 54ms
```

=== All information available from `Test-Connection`

```
PS C:\src\t> Test-Connection -Count 1 -TargetName 'ibm.com' | Format-List * -Force

Ping           : 1
Source         : NB-XXXXXXX
Destination    : ibm.com
Address        : 184.87.3.183
DisplayAddress : 184.87.3.183
Latency        : 59
Status         : Success
BufferSize     : 32
Reply          : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply
```

Comment: I should change your code to this so it works on my PS but it has empty output:
'''$Targets = @('www.ibm.com', 'www.hp.com')
$Results = @()
foreach ($Target in $Targets) {
    $Results += Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName $Target
}
$Results = $Results | Sort-Object -Property Time
$Results | ForEach-Object {"{0} {1}ms" -f $_.Destination, $_.Time }'''

Comment: Is there any output? An error message? Can you manually ping www.ibm.com or www.hp.com successfully? Why did you put the code into the comment? It appears that `Test-Connection` was available in PowerShell 3, so I do not think it is a version problem.

Comment: I didnt put the code in comment, I thought it will show here as formatted text but I was wrong and lazy to correct it here. The code needs computerName instead of targetName as mention before. it will ping and shows the results correctly also shows the sorted list too correctly but when using the last line: foreac-object it only outputs two newlines with ms in them. this shows that the formatting algorithm is not working somehow. my PS version using this command  Get-Host | Select-Object is 5.1.19041.1023

Comment: @NimaNouri, I have added to the answer information that I hope will help. Neither `ping` nor `Test-Connection` will produce COMPUTERNAME. That is a Microsoft term for hostname. When you ping a web site by URL, the hostname is not known.

Comment: PS C:\Users\Nima> Test-Connection -Count 1 -TargetName 'ibm.com' | Format-List * -Force
Test-Connection : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TargetName'.
At line:1 char:26
+ Test-Connection -Count 1 -TargetName 'ibm.com' | Format-List * -Force
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
the only answer I can tell you is that you are wrong about the syntax of the command.